# hibernate validator - validate against String Input when Integer expected

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

How can I validate against String input when Integer value is expected using the hibernate validator? I've tried:

```
@Pattern(regexp="[0-9]+", message="must be Integer") 
private Integer rating;
```

but this works only for String fields and not integers.

So when I type in a String rather than a number I get the following error:

`"UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer."`

Comment: can you provide your entity class...

Comment: oh well, I have simply annotated a field in my entity class as updated above.